# Alternative methods to obtain the derivative of an elementary function (besides the definition, and the sum/product/chain rules)

Tags: functions, derivatives

Given a differentiable function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ which is an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function), what methods are there to calculate the its derivative?

(1) We of cause have the possibility of using the definition itself:
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
$$

(2) We define some basic functions for which we look up their derivative, and use sum, product, and chain rule to calculate $f'(x)$.

What other methods are there?

Comment: Expressing $f$ as a power series would be another common way.

Comment: At points where the derivative exists, the calculation can be carried out by calculating the [**symmetric derivative**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative) or by calculating any **psudo-symmetric derivative** (see near the end [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5991525), or [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02844173); more generally see the 1981 paper [*Parametric differentiation*](https://eudml.org/doc/264788) by Evans/Humke and the 1989 paper [*Pseudo-symmetric differentiation*](https://eudml.org/doc/264870) by Pu/Pu).

Comment: There's [logarithmic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation), which may-or-may-not fall under your case (2).

Comment: We don't have all that many elementary functions. Monomials and polynomials have a clear rule for differentiating. Exponential, sine and cosine are represented by power series convergent everywhere which obey the same differentiation rule. Inverse trig functions and logarithm are a little trickier, but we can invert the derivative for the exponential. There's also algebraic functions, but their derivatives are an extension of the rule for monomials and composite functions

Comment: @Bungo With the big question of how to transform back a power series into a regular function. So far the only method I've ever seen was an OEIS comparation

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I've seen the symmetric derivative, it's a nice variation on the regular derivative! Unluckily, it seldomly simplifies calculations or opens up new paths for differentating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could numerically approximate the derivative. Most numerical methods rely on manipulating [Taylor series expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

(1) The most common of these are finite difference methods. Taylor expansions allow us to write the forward difference, backward difference, and central difference.

Given a small $h > 0$, we have

Forward Difference: Starting from

$$f(x+h) = f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac{1}{2!}h^2f''(x)+\frac{1}{3!}h^3f'''(x)+\frac{1}{4!}h^4f''''(x)+\dots$$

move $f(x)$ to the LHS and divide by $h$ to form

$$f'(x)\approx \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Backward Difference: Starting from

$$f(x-h) = f(x)-hf'(x)+\frac{1}{2!}h^2f''(x)-\frac{1}{3!}h^3f'''(x)+\frac{1}{4!}h^4f''''(x)-\dots$$

move $f(x-h)$ to the RHS, $f'(x)$ to the LHS, and divide by $h$ to form

$$f'(x)\approx \frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}$$

Central Difference: Starting from

$$f(x+h) = f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac{1}{2!}h^2f''(x)+\frac{1}{3!}h^3f'''(x)+\frac{1}{4!}h^4f''''(x)+\dots$$

subtract

$$f(x-h) = f(x)-hf'(x)+\frac{1}{2!}h^2f''(x)-\frac{1}{3!}h^3f'''(x)+\frac{1}{4!}h^4f''''(x)-\dots$$

and then divide by $2h$ to form

$$f'(x)\approx \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$$

[Higher order derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) are known and [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0898716292) is a great introduction to the theory of the finite difference method.

(2) We can apply the method of undetermined coefficients to generate approximations to derivatives.

Suppose $$f'(x)\approx D_hf(x)\equiv Af(x-h) + Bf(x)+Cf(x+h)\tag{1}$$

where $A,B,C$ are constants that we must determine so that $D_hf(x)$ is as accurate as possible. Then, from the Taylor series,

$$f(x-h) = f(x)-hf'(x)+\frac{1}{2!}h^2f''(x)-\frac{1}{3!}h^3f'''(x)+\frac{1}{4!}h^4f''''(x)-\dots\tag{2}$$
$$f(x)=f(x)\tag{3}$$
$$f(x+h) = f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac{1}{2!}h^2f''(x)+\frac{1}{3!}h^3f'''(x)+\frac{1}{4!}h^4f''''(x)+\dots\tag{4}$$

If we multiply $(2),(3),(4)$ by $A,B,C$ and then add, we see from $(1)$ that

\begin{align}
D_hf(x)&=(A+B+C)f(x)+(C-A)hf'(x) + (A+C)\frac{1}{2!}h^2f''(x) + (C-A)\frac{1}{3!}h^3f'''(x)\\&~~~~~+(A+C)\frac{1}{4!}h^4f''''(x)+\dots
\end{align}

Therefore, if

$$D_hf(x)\approx f'(x)$$

for some arbitrary function $f(x)$, we would require that

$$A+B+C=0$$
$$h(C-A)=1$$
$$A+C=0$$

If we solve this system, we will obtain

$$A=-C=-\frac{1}{2h}$$
$$B=0$$

which would then produce our central difference scheme

$$D_hf(x)\equiv \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$$

and

$$D_hf(x)=f'(x)+\frac{1}{3!}h^2f'''(x)+\dots$$

We can also change the coefficients of $A,B,C$ so that $D_hf(x)$ is exact for polynomials of as high degree as possible. This will lead to the well known central difference formula to the second derivative

$$D_h^{(2)}f(x)=\frac{f(x-h)-2f(x)+f(x+h)}{h^2}$$

Comment: Looking at the book, it seems one needs to have studied physics to get the most out of it. While I really like the idea using the Taylor-expansion, what are those Taylor-expansions? I first thought they'd be the Taylor expansion of $f(x)$ at $x= x-h, x=h, x=x+h$ , but in that case, wouldn't they be $f(x+h) = - h·f'(x + h) + f(x + h)+...$?

Comment: @Sudix: See my updates, do you understand the initial Taylor expansions? You don't need to understand a lot of physics to understand these methods (although, it certainly helps when you are studying partial differential equations).

Answer (score 1):

By definition, an elementary function is some finite expression containing certain "basic elementary functions" and operations $+$, $\ldots$, exponentiation, inverse functions, etc. The derivatives of the basic  elementary functions are found from their defining properties and your $(1)$, and the derivative of a "finite expression" containing such such basic functions is found using the well known derivative rules on the "expressional tree" defining such a function. Apart from the derivatives of the basic functions all this is in terms of finite expressions, and requires no further computations of limits, let alone power series or integrals.

The answer to your question therefore is: There are none. But of course there are identities among the basic functions, like $\cos^2 x +\sin^2 x\equiv1$, and such identities may allow to simplify the obtained derivatives. This is a question of "normalization", like replacing $2+3$ by $5$, but is not a "new method" of computing derivatives.

Comment: Which is rather weird. Of cause, the one way everbody is doing it works, but still - something such elementary, and we've got a mere two ways of solving it (of which the first is rarely ever used)?